# compare a string and a line in a docx

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am new to c# and I am developing a program about parsing job resumes, I have some problem about string comparison.

When I compare a string with the line in stringReader, even the string is the same, my output of comparison is false. I am really confused with this.

I have tried Regex.Ismatch and String.Equals. I have tried Regex.replace() to replace the special character in line, but none of them give the correct output.

Some information may helpful:

When I use

```
 Console.WriteLine(Regex.Escape(line.ToString()));
```

I got

```
Job\ Description\ -\ Ensure\ Alignment\ to\ Selected\ Title
```

on screen.

When I call

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("Job Description - Ensure Alignment to Selected Title", @"Job\ Description\ -\ Ensure\ Alignment\ to\ Selected\ Title"));
```

The output I got is true.

But

```
string.Equals("Job Description - Ensure Alignment to Selected Title", line.ToString())
```

gives me false.

Some tricky thing is 
when I call

```
Console.WriteLine(line.ToString().Length);
```

the output is 53

I think the length of

```
Job\ Description\ -\ Ensure\ Alignment\ to\ Selected\ Title
```

should be 52

Here is part of my code:

```
// this part is how I change docx file to a string
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object path = @"D:\testfile1.docx";
            object readOnly = true;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

            for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
            {
                text.Append(docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString());

            }

// this part is the comparison
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(text.ToString()))
            {
                string line = string.Empty;
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                if(string.Equals("Job Description - Ensure Alignment to Selected Title", line.ToString())){
                 Console.WriteLine("correct");}
}
```

Comment: Try this: Output the contents of `text` to file (`File.WriteAllText(@"c:\path", text.ToString()`).  Now open the file and paste in the line from the word doc directly below the "same" line in the new file.  Compare them directly.  If they compare exactly in a plain text viewer, use some kind of hex editor to look at the actual bytes (even the '-' may be different).  If you're on windows, you can simply use powershell's `Format-Hex`

Comment: A Word paragraph will have the "paragraph mark" at the end of it. That would be an ANSI 13 character. In C# this can be represented with `"\r"`, "`\n"` or `char(13)`, as I recall. I'm guessing that's your 53rd character when you calculate the length...